# Django: sending email causes OSError

Tags: django, docker, email, django-rest-framework, smtp

I'm setting up registration proces for my Django REST API. I use "email.send()" function in my SignUpView. When I create new user, it should send him activation link. Unfortunately i get "OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address".

I was looking for some solutions, but all was conected to some problems with sockets. Despite this I tried to change my ports in settings.

My email settings in settings.py:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myemail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD= 'mypassword'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

View i used to signup:

```
class SignUp(APIView):

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = SignUpSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            user = serializer.save(is_active=False)
            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            mail_subject = 'Aktywuj swoje konto w serwisie Podwoozka.'
            message =  'user: ', user.username,'domain', current_site.domain,'uid',urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)).decode(),'token', account_activation_token.make_token(user), 
            to_email = user.email
            email = EmailMessage(
                mail_subject, message, to=[to_email]
            )
            email.send()
            return HttpResponse('Potwierdz email aby zakonczyc rejestracje.')
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

And finally entire Traceback when i use this function:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
api_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
api_1  |     response = get_response(request)
api_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
api_1  |     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
api_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 124, in _get_response
api_1  |     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
api_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
api_1  |     return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
api_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
api_1  |     return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
api_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 495, in dispatch
api_1  |     response = self.handle_exception(exc)
api_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 455, in handle_exception
api_1  |     self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
api_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 492, in dispatch
api_1  |     response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
api_1  |   File "/Dback/races/views.py", line 264, in post
api_1  |     email.send()
api_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 291, in send
api_1  |     return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
api_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 103, in send_messages
api_1  |     new_conn_created = self.open()
api_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 63, in open
api_1  |     self.connection = self.connection_class(self.host, self.port, **connection_params)
api_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 251, in __init__
api_1  |     (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
api_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 336, in connect
api_1  |     self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
api_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 307, in _get_socket
api_1  |     self.source_address)
api_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 727, in create_connection
api_1  |     raise err
api_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 716, in create_connection
api_1  |     sock.connect(sa)
api_1  | OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

I don't know if its important, but im using docker in this project. I heard sometimes there are some problems with outgoing connections from container.

EDIT: I tried to run it in pipenv instead of docker, still not working.
This time its "ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"

Comment: i think you are missing from email address in EmailMessage()

Comment: Check if the docker container has the email port opened.

Comment: I'm not sure if its required, i think if I already say it in settings i don't have to write it 2nd time. Saying it only, becouse i saw some examples with exactly same syntax.

Comment: But i checked, still doeant work with "from" adress

Comment: @Sanip, how can i do that? Im not really familliar with docker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure that you enabled POP access in Gmail:

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7104828?hl=en&visit_id=637244831918669326-2427073497&rd=1

Then, if you receive `Application-specific password required` error, set up an app password for your account:

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?p=InvalidSecondFactor&visit_id=637244831918669326-2427073497&rd=1

Comment: I actually came back to this project recently and did everything from the beginning. This time it's working, but probably it was caused by using password do email account and not an app-specific password. So your answer is perfectly correct.

Comment: @MaciejMycielski did you use application-specific password or the normal password?

Comment: @VivasvanPatel 1st time I used the normal password and it wasn't working. With an app-specific password, everything worked fine.

Comment: ok thank you ... that didnt work for me. 
And after 2 days of digging i gave up and finally used smtplib and ssl in the end.
(https://realpython.com/python-send-email/)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this problem has been resolved with set SMTP_BLCOK = off.

**in ssh or terminal**

You must run the 3 commands in your ssh or terminal:

```
vi /etc/csf/csf.conf
SMTP_BLOCK = "0"
csf -r
```

**in cpanel**

You must follow this path:

```
WHM >‌ Plugins > ConfigServer Security & Firewall > Firewall Configuration > SMTP_BLCOK
```

and set SMTP_BLCOK = OFF